# Collection of Child objects initialized with only the id best practice?

Tags: c#, oop, .net-core

Best practice question.

We receive a request to add a new item.  The addrequest object contains only the properties needed to create the new object, one of which is a list of id's representing a collection of related objects.

At some point the add request gets mapped to a full business object in readiness to be passed to the repository layer.  This includes a collection of association objects with only the id populated.

The repo maps the business object to the dtos for the database and maps back a complete object and a complete collection of related objects once the addition has completed successfully.

The question is....

Should the collection of associated objects be:

- Left alone - an object populated with just an Id
- Fully populated - look up and populate the other properties of the related object
- Replaced - pass the list of ids all the way down to the repo and only use the related object as part of the return

Your thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure there is a clearly established best practice, and it may depend on the specific use case.

Comment: For me, the repo should be using the business object thus the population of the related objects and not a list of ids.

I'm happy with id only because validation has already been passed at this point so the related items already exist.

Others don't like this approach hence the question.